# Cron expression to run twice monthly using day of week with "#'

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm trying to figure out how to setup quartz to run twice monthly specifying the day of week using the symbol "#".

My expression:

```
0 0 8 ? * 6#2,6#4
```

My goal is to run every second and fourth Friday of every month at 8:00

The expression is valid, but it runs only at forth Friday. The second one is ignored.

How to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not way now.

> If the '#' character is used, there can only be one expression in the
>   day-of-week field ("3#1,6#3" is not valid, since there are two
>   expressions).

source: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Answer (score 0):

if fourth is working fine. You can simply separate the two out and load the job again for second friday.

if API does not provide you the solution it always comes down to your implementation and code logic.